# Finding correspondence between two sets of 3d points

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent, points, nonlinear-optimization

I am currently implementing the gradient descent algorithm for finding the best possible transformation of a set of points to another set of points.
The problem I'm having is currently the problem of finding the corresponding points in each set, I used the minimum distance to correspond the points but I ran into the problem that all points correspond to only points on one side
Like for example the 2d image below
[image]

Is there any approach that I can take to resolve this?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I suspect this may be an  `assignment problem`.

Comment: Finally figured it out, Scaled my data to have a mean of zero and a variance of 1 so that they will be distributed around the axis (0,0), this way it was easier to find corresponding points